# Google Login Api with Jquery error

Tags: jquery, google-api

I have implemented LogIn with google in a website using jquery. before some days it was working well but from today its causing problem and giving error.

Site link is http://dev.ganitgurooz.com/.

Error is: **Uncaught TypeError : can't call method authorize of undefined**

my jquery code is: 
    gmlogin:function(){
    var accessToken;
    var config = {
    'client_id': 'MY-Client-Id',
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    };

```
home.auth(config);          
},
auth:function(config) {
gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
console.log(accessToken);
home.validateToken();       
});
},
validateToken:function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token='+accessToken,
data: null,
success: function(response){  
home.getUserInfo();
},  
error: function(error) {
},
dataType: "jsonp" 
});
},
getUserInfo:function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token='+accessToken,
data: null,
success: function(response) {
console.log(response);
var gmail ='gmail';
var dataString         ='gmail='+gmail+'&fname='+response.given_name+'&lname='+response.family_name+'&email='+response.email+'&gmId='+response.id+'&dob='+response.birthday;



$.post(common.getSiteURL() +'/Remote/validateUsers',dataString,function(data){
console.log(data);
var redirect_url = '/';
if (data == "SUCCESS") {                                                   

if(getCookie("redirect_url")){


redirect_url = getCookie("redirect_url");
}


window.location.href = redirect_url ;
}else{


window.location.href='/';
}
});

},
dataType: "jsonp"
});
}
```

Hope anyone can help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got solution of problem Google authorization i found new method of it.

[Authentication and Authorization for Google](http://www.gethugames.in/blog/2012/04/authentication-and-authorization-for-google-apis-in-javascript-popup-window-tutorial.html) **Authentication and Authorization for Google APIs in Javascript popup window – Tutorial**

I am posting my answer here because of It also others.

I am not getting proper response on localhost but its working when i put my code live.
Thanks